# Object reference not set to an instance of an object... Error while using foreach

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, object-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

I am developing a simple program. Accepting an arraylist from Form1 and displaying its contents on form2 and I am getting this error.. Plz enlighten me.. Coding goes like this ..

FORM1.cs..............

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ArrayList alcar;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = textBox1.Text; ; int quantity = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        car c = new car(name, quantity);
        if (alcar != null)
        {
            alcar.Add(c);
        }
        else
        {
            alcar = new ArrayList();
            alcar.Add(c);
        }
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
    public ArrayList getArray()
    {
     return alcar;
    }    
}
class car
{
    string name; int quantity;
    public string NAME
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public int QUANTITY
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set { quantity = value; }
    }
    public car(string n, int q)
    {
        name = n; quantity = q;
    }
}
```

FORM2.cs.........................

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    ArrayList al;
    public Form2()
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        if (al != null)
        {
            al = f1.getArray();
        }
        else
        {
            al = new ArrayList();
            al = f1.getArray();
        }

        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (car c in al)        // this lne is causing error
        {
            label1.Text = c.NAME;
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(c.QUANTITY);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Posting the exception would be very helpful.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? If you're using .NET 2.0 or above, then you should not be using `ArrayList`.

Comment: Reading your code, I think that there are few key concepts in C# you need to learn. I would suggest getting a C# book and learn about refernces and reference types vs. value types.

Answer (score 4):

If `f1.getArray()` returns a `null`, that's the Exception I would expect.

But the issue is here:

```
// In Form2
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

This creates a *new* `Form1` instance, not the instance that you created the car in. It will have nothing in the array. In this new instance, you never initialize `alcar` or populate it, so it is `null` by default. Getting this `null` object and trying to iterate over it is where your error comes from.

Rethink your design so you pass the array to the second form directly (either on a custom constructor or a property).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write `new` in the field declaration itself, which will simplify your code a lot:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    ArrayList alcar = new ArrayList(); // DO THIS HERE!

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = textBox1.Text; ; int quantity = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        car c = new car(name, quantity);

        //JUST ADD - without checking for null!
        alcar.Add(c);

        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
    public ArrayList getArray()
    {
         return alcar; //its non-null - guaranteed!
    }
    //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your creating a new instance of Form1 in the ctor of Form2, it never shows it's UI, and never gets clicked therefore when you say al=f1.getArray(); in the ctor of Form2 it returns a null reference.

Use the reference of Form1 that exists already instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList alcar isn't instantiated in Form1 unless the button is clicked. You need to check for null and instantiate alcar in the GetArray method of Form1. Or, instantiate alcar in Form1's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In Form2, you create a new instance of Form1 :
`Form1 f1 = new Form1();`

You never initiated `alcar` for that particular instance. You need to get the instance of Form1 where the user have clicked button1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ArrayList getArray()
{
    if(null == alcar)
         alcar = new ArrayList();

    return alcar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList alcar;
created without element and when you call the GetArray() will return it null and you have your exception 
one of the sollution you can make  in Form1

```
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(alcar);
        f2.Show();
```

and in form2

```
     ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
     public Form2(ArrayList  alcar)
     {
         al = alcar;
         InitializeComponent();
```